# Error while setting history server in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

All the datanodes are UP and running,however still getting following error while setting up history server(mapreduce2) in hadoop.

> resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'curl -sS -L -w
>   '%{http_code}' -X PUT -T /usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hadoop/mapreduce.tar.gz
>   'http://ambari1.devcloud.247-inc.net:50070/webhdfs/v1/hdp/apps/2.3.4.0-3485/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz?op=CREATE&user.name=hdfs&overwrite=True&permission=444''
>
> returned status_code=403.  {   "RemoteException": {
>       "exception": "IOException", 
>       "javaClassName": "java.io.IOException", 
>       "message": "Failed to find datanode, suggest to check cluster health."
>    }
>
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the name node, Run the below command to ensure the data nodes are running properly and accessible from namenode

```
bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

and you can see reports like

```
-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 1 (1 total, 0 dead)

Name: 127.0.0.1:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 176945963008 (164.79 GB)
DFS Used: 2140192768 (1.99 GB)
Non DFS Used: 42513027072 (39.59 GB)
DFS Remaining: 132292743168(123.21 GB)
DFS Used%: 1.21%
DFS Remaining%: 74.76%
Last contact: Wed Jan 06 20:04:51 IST 2016
```

If you see 0 datanodes, the configuration must be wrong

Comment: Thanks.It worked finally.
Firstly,it was showing 0 nodes,however both the DNs were UP.
Restarted it,and report cmd worked.Then started history server and it was finally up.